# Preserve insert order of object array after sort in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, quicksort

I've got a array of objects like the following:

```
var a = {
 "TypeID" : 15,
 "Attr1" : "Something"
};

var b = {
 "TypeID" : 17,
 "Attr1" : "Something"
};

var c = {
 "TypeID" : 15,
 "Attr1" : "Something"
};

var d = {
 "TypeID" : 15,
 "Attr1" : "Something"
};

var e = {
 "TypeID" : 1,
 "Attr1" : "Something"
};

var objectArray = new Array();
objectArray.push(a);
objectArray.push(b);
objectArray.push(c);
objectArray.push(d);
```

I tried to sort the array using the TypeID as the value for order, however I need to preserve the order insert. I meant, the final order must be the following:

```
e,a,c,d,b
```

But when I implement the classical sort algorithms(Bubble or Quicksort) I get the array ordered but the insert order of similiar value(TypeID) are in different possition.

I tried to order at first time similar types of objects, but got lost with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking about is how do you implement a sort function that preserves the initial order of objects that have identical sort keys, then the only ways I know of to do that are:

1. Use a sort algorithm that is guaranteed to preserve the original order for ties
2. Add a secondary key that is the original sort ordinal and use a sort algorithm that looks at the secondary sort key for ties.

Comment: I've read about stable sort algorithms and I implemented the Bubble algorithm however I'm getting undesired results.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez - if you want help with your specific code, you have to include that code.  I've told you what the options are.  FYI, why are you implementing your own sort algorithm when you can use `.sort(fn)` which is built into the Array object.